# Does Monero have any connection to the Esperanto community other than its name?

Tags: kovri, esperanto

In addition to the Esperanto name Monero, the name [Kovri](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri) was chosen for another Monero related project. Is there some deeper connection between the Esperanto and Monero communities? Or does part of the Monero community just like to use Esperanto vocabulary because of the project name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no official relationship. The Monero name was inherited from the original developer who never revealed any connection to the Esperanto community other than providing the [definition](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=563821.msg6272312#msg6272312):

> Bitmonero = bit + monero
>   monero = mono (money) + ero (bit) = coin (esperanto language)

There are some unnoficial connections such as an Esperantist named [Kaja](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants) accepting Monero for Esperanto lessons and an attempt from longtime Monero user dnale0r to encourage more Monero users to begin [learning the language](http://weuse.cash/esperanto-corner/)

Answer (score 4):

Esperanto means "one who hopes" and the language itself is an amalgam of other European languages in hopes to unite people under a common language.  I think the philosophy kind of spills over into Monero a bit :)